# Require only set of nested parameters Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I make a request to the server with a Json like this

```
{"user" : { "name" : "name", "email" : "email", "password":"pswd"}}
```

So i want to only accept this format Jsons.
I made this:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)
```

But that doesnt work, i can send more parameters. I want to receive only that format or otherwise, it give an error.

Thanks!

EDIT:
I used the answer from Carlos Ramirez III, for not receiving more data than necessary, but now i am receiving less data than necessary.
Should this be implemented on the data base or in receiving parameters?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails' strong parameters functions as a *white-list*, meaning that the attributes you specify there will be the only ones that are considered (any extra parameters will be discarded).

If you are worried about extra parameters being processed, resulting in bad data, then what you have will already take care of that.

If you *must* send an error if there are any extra parameters, you'll need to hand-code that yourself.

E.g.

```
extra_params = params.keys - [:name, :email, :password]
if extra_params.size != 0
   # raise an error here in whatever way you wish
   raise "Invalid parameters: #{extra_params}"
end
```